# Persist Prometheus data between Kind cluster restarts

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, persistent-volumes, kind

I'm running k8s cluster with Kind. I'm using [this](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/c48edfdd457ea3bba6e807ae387dfb715015edcb/charts/prometheus) Prometheus chart. I want to persist Prometheus data between Kind cluster restarts in a given directory of my local machine.

How to configure abovementioned chart as well as Kind installation to always map Prometheus data to a given directory on my computer so that the data is not lost after Kind cluster restart?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

You can choose `storageClassName: local-storage` for `persistentVolumeclaims` by setting that in `values.yaml` file during helm install or via `--set` option in cli:

```
helm upgrade prometheus-community \
prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack \ 
--set server.persistentVolume.storageClass=local-storage
```

As per the [charts PVC templates](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/templates/pvc.yaml#L22), you can specify the `storageClassName` to `local-storage`